# Can you change the default JS operators' behavior?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to modify the default operators of JavaScript. For example, when you execute the following command: `2 + 2`, I would like to change what the `+` does depending on whether it's even or odd (as an example).

Comment: no, you can not overload operators in javascript.

Comment: @OJKwon This isn't operator overloading, since he wants to change the behavior for built-in types, not user-defined types.